# Installing R packages on a GCE hosted google colab Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install the calendR package on colab.

I am using the following:

```
install.packages("calendR")

library(calendR)
```

But this errors out with the following:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

also installing the dependencies ‘magick’, ‘ggimage’


Warning message in install.packages("calendR"):
“installation of package ‘magick’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("calendR"):
“installation of package ‘ggimage’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("calendR"):
“installation of package ‘calendR’ had non-zero exit status”

Error in library(calendR): there is no package called ‘calendR’
Traceback:

1. library(calendR)
```

Anyone know how to install this?

Comment: We need to know the google runtime environment you used. Is it a local one or hosted on a GCE VM?

Comment: I wasn't aware colab could be hosted locally? it is hosted on google

Comment: By default, colab is a jupyter notebook linked to a  Python 3 Google Compute Engine backend which is a docker container based on ubuntu 18.04. Are you using this resource?

Comment: As far as I am aware - yes.  If it helps, I access all my notebooks from https://colab.research.google.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Default kernel

Google colab uses Python 3 Google Compute Engine backend based on docker container with ubuntu 18.04 by default.
It is designed for python and has the ipython kernel.
However, There is R installed as well.
To install `calendR`, create and run a new cell with this content:

```
! add-apt-repository -y ppa:cran/imagemagick
! apt-get update
! apt-get install -y libmagick++-dev
! R -e "install.packages('calendR')"
```

This will execute IPython styled shell commands. Then you can do things like this in a new cell:

```
! R -e "library(calendR)"
```

## IR kernel

Colab can be also host other kernels like ir for R.
Then, the shell commands can be executed using R commands:

```
system("add-apt-repository -y ppa:cran/imagemagick")
system("apt-get update")
system("apt-get install -y libmagick++-dev")
install.packages("calendR")
library("calendR")
```

Comment: Ah I have actually started a notebook with the R kernal, so those commands won't work

Comment: Do `system("add-apt-repository -y ppa:cran/imagemagick")` and so on instead in your cell

Comment: @Joseph I revised my answer

Comment: marked it as answered as that worked